# The value in log is changed ,when I change the value in reactive

Tags: vuejs3, reactive

The value in the two console log below is the same

```
    const ob1 = reactive({ a: 0, b: { c: 1 } })
    console.log(ob1, "111111111")
    ob1.a = 10
    console.log(ob1, "111111111")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmL81.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing on the console log is actually the value in the memory of the object, not the snapshot. So when you change the value of the object, the console log will be updated accordingly. It does not only happen with reactive but also happens with all the JS objects.

If you want to see the snapshot of an object at a time on the console log, you should do this:

```js
const ob1 = reactive({ a: 0, b: { c: 1 } })
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ob1)), "111111111")
ob1.a = 10
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ob1)), "111111111")
```